# could n't find ABI constructor in my input data

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, abi

I have developed the solidity code and need to verify the smart contract but I could not find Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded check the screenshots, i have developed in testnet

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what is your question. Where exactly are you unable to find the encoded arguments? Why didn't you simply print them when you deployed the contract? Where exactly are you now looking for them? (and no, this screenshot doesn't really answer this question).

Comment: I have asked a related question in the past, you might find [the answer to it](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/65171/16043) helpful.

Comment: From the look at the screenshot it seems your contract constructor has not received any parameters.