# get constructor args from contract deploy tx

Tags: evm, abi

this question comes from this post: [What does etherscan mean by "Constructor Arguments (ABI-Encoded and is the last bytes of the Contract Creation Code above)"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/what-does-etherscan-mean-by-constructor-arguments-abi-encoded-and-is-the-last/65171#65171)

My goal is to read contract deployment tx's, parse the `data` field and be able to determine the constructor args used in the deployment.

That post talks about a set of bytes in the beginning of the data that tells the evm where the constructor begins but taking that logic to OTHER contract deployments, the bytes in the same location dont appear to say the same thing.

So tldr - how can i reliably retrieve the constructor args from the encoded abi that is within a deployment tx data field?

Thanks so much